# Real number Factorization Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

I know that Integer Factorization Problem is NP-Hard. It is very importance for RSA Cryptosystem. Let p and q are prime and $N=pq$, if we know $N$, it is very difficult to compute $p$ and $q$. However, what happen if one of them is a real number or at least not prime?

In detail, If we know the product $KR$ of a real number $R \in \mathbb{R}$ and an Integer number $K\in \mathbb{Z}$, is it difficult to compute K and R? Anf if it happened, how this assumption could be prove?

Comment: Then the factorization won't be unique. For example $2\cdot\sqrt{2}=4\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Also, you should never talk about real numbers when discussing algorithms. Decimal numbers, rational numbers, algebraic numbers, sure, but real numbers in general cannot be used in algorithms (they cannot be computed with using finite operations).

Comment: There are many solution for p,q so that we can not determine which is the true answer. In this case can i say that it is difficult to find p and q that pq=N?

Comment: Please also note that integer factorization is _not_ NP-Hard. To our current knowledge we know it sits in the intersection of co-NP and NP and _probably_ outside (BP)P and inside BQP. It being NP-Hard would also mean it's NP-complete and that would have all sorts of crazy complexity theoretical implications.

Answer (score 0):

That problem has infinitely many solutions because $KR = (Ki) \cdot(R/i)$ are solutions for all $0\neq i \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: There are many solution for p,q so that we can not determine which is the true answer. In this case can i say that it is difficult to find p and q that pq=N?

Comment: No, it's not difficult. It's trivial: Just divide $N$ by some non-zero integer $u$ and you have a representation of $N$ in the form $N=uv$ with $u \in \Bbb Z$ and $v \in \Bbb R$ (in $\Bbb Q$ actually).

Comment: I do not understand clearly. I think that, if we only know N=pq, we can not know which p, q is extract solution. Example: If N=100, i think we can not determine p=2, q=50 is right or p=10, q=10 is right.... We can brute-force to calculate all pair that available (in a finite set) but we do not know which pair that use in original, can't we?

Comment: You said you had a cryptosystem that is hard to break if it is hard to find a factorization of $N$. But factorizations are trivial, thus breaking your cryptosystem is trivial. What cryptosystem are you using exactly? Systems that use that factorization is hard require the factorization of N which is unique up to order and units.

Comment: Factorization over $\Bbb Z$ is unique up to order and units. That it's hard to compute the factozization means it's hard to compute Euler's $\varphi(N)$ which is needed. What quantity does your system need?  Just determining the factorization is pointless, you must be forced to USE it, and without knowing it you MUST be stuck in the computations.

Comment: I want to create a new protocol in that the user can send a public real number that is a product of two other real number. It is required that, if an attacker can capture the public value, he can not recover exactly two factor that created it before. Can i do this?

Comment: You can do that. But what does the intended recipient Bob do with the value? How is the value more useful to Bob than it is to Carl?